# Regulate and verify an AC current to test a current transducer sensor

Tags: current-measurement

Firstly my background in software so this is a bit of foreign territory for me.

I have the requirement to monitor an AC current between 0 and 3 Amps. The plan so far in to use a non invasive current transducer sensor connected to an analogue input on a device connected to a PC. Something like this appears to be what we need: http://www.robotshop.com/uk/10a-ac-current-sensor.html

The problem I have is I don't have access to the equipment we are to monitor until we install so I need an (inexpensive) way to reproduce, control and verify an AC current passing through the CT Sensor.

In the live system we will be getting a sharp rise from ~0A to aproximatly 1.2A (aprox 600ms) which should last for about 3 seconds then a sharp drop back down to ~0A. The system will also need to identify when a gradual rise or drop occurs (over 600ms) as this indicates improper operation and so I will also need to simulate this. Something with a dial would be perfect.

Would simply a plug in dimmer switch, plug in electricity meter/current monitor connected to something like a lamp be able to do the job or is there something more suitable?

Thanks

Comment: That sensor isn't clear-cut as to what its output represents. I'd be tempted to use one with a better data sheet.

Comment: Hi Andy. There didn't seem much in the way of choice for such a low level of AC current but the datasheet states the output is 0-5 VDC, proportional to RMS input current (sine wave). Which from my understanding would mean if a current of 1A is passing throught the then output would be 0.5V (or 0.1 * the supplied voltage)

Comment: This is also the reason we need to be able test the the equipment by controling and verifying the current passing through the transducer.

Comment: The data sheet also says AC Amps (RMS) = SensorValue/100 and this doesn't tally.

Comment: Hi Andy.
I think thats something I will just have to work out once i've got it. Provided it is proportional and follows some sort of logic I should be able to convert in code. 
Unless you can suggest another device?
The main question is really how to regulate the test current so I can test, develop and calibrate.
Thanks

Comment: 1.0 How fast is the sharp rise and fall? 2.) How slow is the gradual rise and fall?

Comment: Ideally we want to be taking readings about every 200-300 ms. Under proper operation the current should go from aprox 0-1.2A in about 600 ms and reamin there for 3 seconds. If it takes over a second to reach 1.2A then this may indicate a problem. We need to be able to plot these readings later on for auditing and anlysis purposes but this will all be handled in code provided we can get the readings.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it dosn't look like there is an easy answer, I might just have to test on site (which if you knew the sort of place you would understand my reluctance).

Answer (score 1):

Your basic plan sounds reasonable, But...

I would not recommend a dimmer switch to regulate the current. They chop up the AC waveform, which will stress the RMS  calculation part of the sensor, and probably give you inaccurate readings. Rather find a selection of incandescent / halogen light bulbs and connect them one by one.

Note that you can increase the current seen by the sensor, by passing the wire through it a few times.  Perhaps don't wind tight coils around it, but if you keep it fairly loose, each time the current passes through the hole it will be counted again. So you can fairly easily and accurately double or quadruple the current from one lightbulb, to try out the full range of the sensor.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the reply. The problem with using a set of bulbs is that I need to regulate the supply live to loosly simulate the equiment we are monitoring. In the live system we will be getting a sharp rise from ~0A to aproximatly 1.2A which should last for about 3 seconds then a sharp drop back down to ~0A. The system will also need to identify when a gradual rise or drop occurs as this indicates improper operation and so I will also need to simulate this. Something with a dial would be perfect.

Comment: 60W = 0.5A @ 120V.  30W = 0.25A.  Connect them up with  switches (one with 2 60W + 1 30W).  Add other 30W as needed.  Easiest way to change load.  Dimmer switch will not work as well.

Comment: Maybe you can use a variable auto-transformer (variac) to supply current to your light bulb during the test phase (must be an incandescent bulb such as tungsten filament or halogen type). When you ramp up the variac voltage, the current will also increase. You will also need a way to independently verify the current. I would suggest using a good multimeter, and also a current probe with an oscilloscope. These would be used only to confirm the operation of your sensor during test phase. Crude, but should work OK.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it dosn't look like there is an easy answer, I might just have to test on site (which if you knew the sort of place you would understand my reluctance).

Comment: @apc I don't mean to discourage you from testing it first. The only thing is that the current sensor might not read true RMS when used with a light dimmer, so the electricity meter will diverge from the current reading. So I'd recommend 1) calibrate or check the sensor with a known, resistive load. 2) try it with the light dimmer, and 3) just connect a variable voltage to your analog data acquisition gadget, to test the rest of the chain. Perhaps a simple potentiometer connected to 0 and 5 V.